# Is there a way to instantiate a new client on server side by firebase cloud function?

Tags: getstream-io

I am developing an app and trying to implement news feed by getstream.io using react native and firebase. 
Is there a way to generate user token by using firebase cloud function. If there is, would you please give me a pointer how i can do so? (the snippet of codes in cloud function side and client side would be super helpful..) 
I have seen similar questions, only to find out no specific tutorial.. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For the cloud function side you need to create a `https.onRequest` endpoint that calls `createUserToken` like so:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stream = require('getstream');

const client = stream.connect('YOUR_STREAM_KEY', 'YOUR_STREAM_SECRET', 'YOUR_STREAM_ID');

exports.getStreamToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const token = client.createUserToken(req.body.userId);
    return { token };
});
```

After that, deploy with `firebase deploy --only functions` in the terminal & get the url for the function from your firebase dashboard.

Then you can use the url in a POST request with axios or fetch or whatever like this:

```
const { data } = axios({
    data: {
        userId: 'lukesmetham', // Pass the user id for the user you want to generate the token for here.
    },
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'CLOUD_FUNC_URL_HERE',
});
```

Now, `data.token` will be the returned stream token and you can save it to AsyncStorage or wherever you want to store it. Are you keeping your user data in firebase/firestore or stream itself? With a bit more background I can add to the above code for you depending on your setup!  Hopefully this helps!

**UPDATE:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stream = require('getstream');

const client = stream.connect('YOUR_STREAM_KEY', 'YOUR_STREAM_SECRET', 'YOUR_STREAM_ID');

// The onCreate listener will listen to any NEW documents created
// in the user collection and will only run when it is created for the first time.

// We then use the {userId} wildcard (you can call this whatever you like.) Which will
// be filled with the document's key at runtime through the context object below.

exports.onCreateUser = functions.firestore.document('user/{userId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    // Snapshot is the newly created user data.
    const { avatar, email, name } = snapshot.val();
    const { userId } = context.params; // this is the wildcard from the document param above.

    // you can then pass this to the createUserToken function
    // and do whatever you like with it from here
    const streamToken = client.createUserToken(userId);
});
```

Let me know if that needs clearing up, these docs are super helpful for this topic too

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Comment: Thanks Luke! It worked :) I will be keeping my user data in firebase/firestore.

Comment: Awesome! So the if you're storing the data in firestore you can use the `onCreate` listener in cloud functions. I'll update my answer slightly for you 